# Api return file c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

my question is I am connecting with an api and this give me a file response.

this is the result file in my api

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

return result;
```

and i use this ajax to call the api

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "http://localhost/api/Piezas/Imagen/" + @Model.PiezaId,
        contentType: "application/octet-stream",
        success: function (datos) {
            //$("#image").attr("src", "data:image/png;base64," + datos);
        }
    });
```

that file is an image.the question is how can i converted to used or assigned to an img src="" maybe using jquery.

Comment: If you want to return an image, the easiest way is to convert the `byte[]` containing the image data in to a base64 string, then display that as the `src` of the `<img />` element.

Comment: could you give me an example, please